# How to count same strings in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array from strings and I want to count the same strings. Is it possible? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
arr = np.array(sys.stdin.read().split(), dtype = '>U20')
print(arr)
```

Comment: What do you mean "count the strings"? Do you want `len(arr)`?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: I mean the number of the same words.

Comment: I have a array from words and it has many same words, I need to count them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
import collections, numpy

collections.Counter(arr)
```

Or

```
unique, counts = numpy.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's all I need