# Vectorize simple for loop in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I'm pretty new to **numpy** and I'm trying to **vectorize a simple for loop** for performance reasons, but I can't seem to come up with a solution. I have a numpy array with unique words and for each of these words i need the number of times they occur in another numpy array, called array_to_compare. The number is passed to a third numpy array, which has the same shape as the unique words array.
Here is the code which contains the for loop:

```
import numpy as np

unique_words = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
array_to_compare = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'd'])
vector_array = np.zeros(len(unique_words))

for word in np.nditer(unique_words):
    counter = np.count_nonzero(array_to_compare == word)
    vector_array[np.where(unique_words == word)] = counter

vector_array = [2. 1. 0. 1.]    #the desired output
```

I tried it with np.where and np.isin, but did not get the desired result. I am thankful for any help!

Comment: While the proposed `duplicate` does suggest using `Counter` or `unique`, it doesn't return the result in the desired array form.  The answers provided here do that.  I'm reopening it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630204/how-to-count-same-strings-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `numpy` comparison of array values using `broadcasting`:

```
In [76]: unique_words[:,None]==array_to_compare
Out[76]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
In [77]: (unique_words[:,None]==array_to_compare).sum(1)
Out[77]: array([2, 1, 0, 1])

In [78]: timeit (unique_words[:,None]==array_to_compare).sum(1)
9.5 µs ± 2.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But `Counter` is also a good choice:

```
In [72]: %%timeit
    ...: c=Counter(array_to_compare)
    ...: [c[key] for key in unique_words]
12.7 µs ± 30.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Your use of `count_nonzero` can be improved with

```
In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: words=unique_words.tolist()
    ...: vector_array = np.zeros(len(words))
    ...: for i,word in enumerate(words):
    ...:     counter = np.count_nonzero(array_to_compare == word)
    ...:     vector_array[i] = counter
    ...: 
23.4 µs ± 505 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Iteration on lists is faster than on arrays (`nditer` doesn't add much).  And `enumerate` lets us skip the `where` test.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a `Counter` and a list comprehension to solve this:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...:
   ...: unique_words = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
   ...: array_to_compare = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'd'])

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: counter = Counter(array_to_compare)

In [4]: counter
Out[4]: Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})

In [5]: vector_array = np.array([counter[key] for key in unique_words])

In [6]: vector_array
Out[6]: array([2, 1, 0, 1])
```

Assembling the `Counter` is done in linear time and iterating through your `unique_words` is also linear.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @DanielLenz's answer, but using `np.unique` to create a `dict`:

```
import numpy as np
unique_words = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
array_to_compare = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'd'])
counts = dict(zip(*np.unique(array_to_compare, return_counts=True)))
result = np.array([counts[word] if word in counts else 0 for word in unique_words])
[2 1 0 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is a lot faster than my for-loop and slightly faster than the solution from Daniel Lenz